# Different Poincaré maps for same Equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I've seen the [Wolfram Poincaré example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/PoincareSections.html).

I'd like to modify this sample in order to have a list of Poincaré maps. In the example the event is captured only when `Mod[t, 2 Pi] == 0`. I want to create a map of angles (0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2, 2Pi for example) and create the Poincaré for every angle, in order to create an animation showing the map for every angle.

Obviously I can create data for every angle, putting the the example inside a `Table` command and varying the angle, but it seems a waste of time, because I must perform `NDSolve` every time.

Instead it can be helpful to find a way to use `NDSolve` only once and save directly the list of data for all angles that I want.

I've tried to change `Mod[t, 2 Pi] == 0` to `Mod[t, 2 Pi] == 0 || Mod[t, Pi] == 0`, because I wanted to create a unique list, check it's length and then rearraing data in some way in order to obtain the map list, but I obtain the following error

```
Part::partw: "Part 1 of {} does not exist.
```

And data is

```
{{{}}, {}}[[-1, 1]]
```

Why I obtain this error and how can I have different sections using `NDSolve` only once?

Comment: I updated the answer to show many-events animation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**============== update - animation ==============**

This animation has about 50 frames - meaning it's obtained from tracking 50 independent events during single run of numerical solver:

[image]

Code is simply given by:

```
evs = Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == # & /@ (Range[0, 2 Pi - #, #] &@(2 Pi/50));

data = Block[{δ = 0.15, γ = 0.3}, Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] + δ x'[t] - x[t] + 
        x[t]^3 == γ Cos[ t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[Evaluate@evs, 
       Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}, Round[100 Mod[t, 2 π]]]]}, {}, {t, 0, 
      200000}, MaxSteps -> ∞]]];

Export["test.gif",
 Table[ListPlot[data[[2]][[k]], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0], 
   PlotRange -> {1.8 {-1, 1}, 1.3 {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 450], {k, 1, 50, 1}]
 ]
```

**============== older - testing grounds ==============**

Put independent events in `List` when you need a few of them. Then to separate while Sow/Reap - use tags in Sow - for example for 4 different events. I'll show all of them on a single plot to compare. Just use Manipulate or Animate or ListAnimate for your goal.

```
data = Block[{δ = 0.15, γ = 0.3}, 
   Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] + δ x'[t] - x[t] + 
        x[t]^3 == γ Cos[ t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[{Mod[t, 2 π] == 0, Mod[t, 2 π] == π/2, 
        Mod[t, 2 π] == π, Mod[t, 2 π] == (3 π)/2}, 
       Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}, Round@Mod[t, 2 π]]]}, {}, {t, 0, 
      100000}, MaxSteps -> ∞]]];


ListPlot[data[[2]], ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, All}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0025]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. it solved my problem.

Comment: Nice plot! Looks like pastel.

Comment: @chris it's the new default color palette in Mathematica 10, available for free for the Raspberry Pi. See the documentation of [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotTheme.html).

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Dear Vitaliy, you seem to be very versed in these functionalities of Mathematica, whenever you have some time, could you help out a bit here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63484/poincar%C3%A9-map-for-dynamic-billiard Thanks a lot in advance.