# Poincaré map for dynamic billiard

Tags: dynamic, animation

There's a very nice demonstration of dynamic billiard written by Dan S. Reznik that can be found on demonstrations wolfram(along with the code): [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DynamicBilliardsInEllipse/)

I was thinking whether it would be possible to draw the [Poincaré map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map) of the system for different setups (different parameters: initial angle etc), or for a whole run, meaning an animated Poincaré map (like the [animated map for the kicked rotator on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kicked_rotator)).

The aim is to draw a Poincaré map for a run, if possible, by run I mean: as you see in the image below, you can press the "play" button for "start position angle" and see the animation.

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to Dan S. Reznik again for this beautiful piece of code.

Comment: I did this in Excel once...

Comment: focalRadius function is missing

Comment: it seems the function you want is getEllipseRefls. You should be able to extract from it the trajectory in order to build your Poincare map (?)

Comment: @chris yes indeed, but it runs without it, just remove the tick of "foci" (see image), and it'll be fine.

Comment: so what is it you want to slice? extract x position at y=0? For Poincare maps I know you would plot e.g. x and $\dot x$ but here it is not clear.

Comment: @chris well yeah a perpendicular plane passing through $x=0$ would already be a good start, because once we know how to draw the poincaré maps, then we can change these things up. I guess for our purposes we can fix the magnitude of $d\vec x / dt$ to a constant.

Comment: @Phonon I wasn't (entirely) ignoring your invitation.  It looked complicated and I didn't have time yesterday.  I guess chris's answer is what you were looking for, though.  Generally (I thought), the first-return function (Poincaré map) is defined on a section through an initial condition that produces a periodic orbit in phase space (position-angle space in this case).  I have trouble seeing that that is what chris's code produces, but the images have structure and are therefore interesting nonetheless.  Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the techniques of such systems that have discontinuous jumps in the velocity, nor with what is known, if anything, about Poincaré maps of them.

Comment: Yes, I saw it.  Pretty cool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could start with a simple hack of your code to extract the intersections;
Something like

```
  {x1, y1} = Transpose[line]; 
  {x2, y2} = Transpose[RotateLeft[line]];
  gr2 = {(x1^2 - x1*x2 + y1*(-y1 + y2)), (y1 - y2)} // Transpose // Most;
```

which can be encapsulated in the `ellipseSimLowLevel` as follows

```
  ellipseSimLowLevel[ellPos_, θ_, aimAt_, refls_, ella_, ellb_, showFocii_] := 
  Module[{sph = Circle[{0, 0}, 1.], pt, rhat, nfact = .5, ab, 
  pr = 1.5, line, gr, fdist, focii, ellX, x1, y1, x2, y2, gr2},
  ab = {ella, ellb};
 ellX = ella*clamp[ellPos, -1, 1];
 pt = {ellX, ellipseY[ellX, ab]};
 fdist = focalRadius[ella, ellb];
 focii = 
 If[ella > 
  ellb, {{-fdist, 0}, {fdist, 0}}, {{0, -fdist}, {0, fdist}}];
 rhat = 
 Switch[aimAt, "f1", unit[focii[[1]] - pt], "f2", 
 unit[focii[[2]] - pt], _,(*-r2d[θ Degree].normEllipse[pt,
 ab]*)r2d[θ Degree].{0, -1}];
 line = getEllipseRefls[pt, rhat, ab, refls][[All, 1]];
 gr = {{Scale[sph, ab, {0, 0}]}, {Black, Line[line], 
  PointSize[Medium], Point[line]},
 {PointSize[Large], Red, Thickness[Large], 
  Arrow[{pt - nfact*rhat, pt}]},
 If[showFocii, {PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[focii]}, {}]};
 gr = Graphics[gr, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> {450, 450}, PlotRange -> {{-pr, pr}, {-pr, pr}}];
 (* NEW PART *)
{x1, y1} = Transpose[line]; 
{x2, y2} = Transpose[RotateLeft[line]];
 gr2 = {(x1^2 - x1*x2 + y1*(-y1 + y2)), (y1 - y2)} // Transpose // Most;
 gr2 = Graphics[Map[Point, gr2], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> {450, 450}];
 Row@{gr, gr2}
 (* END OF NEW PART *)
 ];
```

Then the above Manipulate produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Okay, is there a way to put a manipulate bar next to the others, that would allow to change the coordinates through which the plane of intersection with phase space passes? sounds unlikely, thought I'd ask :(

Comment: sure: you just have to find the intersections of the lines with your plane...

Comment: I want to vote this up 1000 times! Thank you very much!