# Oval or Bunimovich stadium

Tags: dynamic, geometry, animation

The dynamic billiard demonstration, that can be found on wolfram demonstrations ([here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DynamicBilliardsInEllipse/)), is only designed for an ellipsoid-shape boundary(snapshot below).

- The idea is to have a dynamic billiard with oval or [stadium-shape billiard (Bunimovich stadium)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards).

---

**A snapshot of the demonstration available on wolfram, with only ellipsoid boundaries:**

[image]

---

**Bunimovich stadium:**

[image]

Characteristic: The Bunimovich stadium as boundary for the dynamical billiard, gives rise to chaotic motion.

Image taken from [scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Microwave_billiards_and_quantum_chaos).

---

**Details on oval-shape boundary:**

- Transformed ellipsoid, into oval (quadrupole), parametrized by the radius of curvature R
  of the boundary as a function of the angle $\phi$ between the tangent vector and the x-direction:

$$R(\phi)=1+\delta \cos(2\phi)$$

With $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$ (one example for could be $\delta=0.07$).

Alternatively, relation between the $x,y$ coordinates and $\phi$ are given as follows: 
$$
x(\phi)= \sin(\phi)+\frac{\delta}{2}\sin(\phi)+\frac{\delta}{6}\sin(3\phi)
$$
$$
y(\phi)=-\cos(\phi)+\frac{\delta}{2}\cos(\phi)-\frac{\delta}{6}\cos{3\phi}
$$

Some visualisation of such boundary: 
[image]

---

- **Are there also parametric equations for the Bunimovich stadium? Similar to the ones provided for the oval boundary.**

---

**References:**

Parametrization and image from: [Semiclassical Transition from an Elliptical
to an Oval Billiard](http://arxiv.org/pdf/chao-dyn/9611006v1.pdf), by Martin Sieber.

The code for the dynamic billiard, written by Dan S. Reznik, can be found [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DynamicBilliardsInEllipse/).

Comment: Of course I know how to do all this because I've worked on it extensively, but I don't think an answer is within the scope of this Q&A format. You would have to narrow down your question to a specific Mathematica issue. I would prefer to post my own code instead of trying to modify the code you posted without any comments.

Comment: Closely related: [Poincaré map for dynamic billiard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63484/245). Both  are essentially requests for code, building on a copy of the same demonstration authored by Dan Reznik.

Comment: Yes, using a case distinction. But as I said initially, you have to make your question more specific so that anyone who answers won't get dragged into an extended discussion trying to hit a moving target because the goal is initially set too broadly. E.g., is speed a main concern, or code readability, or user-friendliness, or extensibility to non-convex shapes, etc. Seems to me like a tutorial would be needed, too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My defined function `next` find `{nextpoint, nextdirection}` value from `{startpoint, startdirection}` using `NSolve`.

```
next[{sp_, sd_}][δ_] := Module[{φ, sol, fp, fd},
  sol = NSolve[{{x[φ, δ], y[φ, δ]} == 
      sp + t sd, Abs[t] > 10^(-9), 0 <= φ < 2 π}, {t, φ}, Reals]// Quiet;
  sol = If[Length[sol] > 0, sol[[1]]];
  fp = {x[φ, δ], y[φ, δ]} /. sol;
  fd = rDirec[sd, (D[y[φ, δ], φ]/D[x[φ, δ], φ] /. sol)];
  {fp, fd}
]
```

and second function `rDirec` is to decide reflected direction that is transformed by the following diagram.

[image]

```
rDirec[d_, m_] := With[{sd = Normalize[N@d], θ = ArcTan[m]},
  RotationTransform[θ][ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}][
     RotationTransform[-θ][sd]]] // Normalize
]
```

This is your function for drawing.

```
x[φ_, δ_] := Sin[φ] + δ/2 Sin[φ] + δ/6 Sin[3φ];
y[φ_, δ_] := -Cos[φ] + δ/2 Cos[φ] - δ/6 Cos[3φ];
```

now you can use these `next` and `rDirec` for reflecting process of any parametric functions like this.

```
Manipulate[
 list = NestList[next[#][δ] &, {{x[s, δ], y[s, δ]},{1, 1.7}},20]//Quiet;
 ParametricPlot[{x[φ, δ], y[φ, δ]}, {φ, 0, 4 π},
  Epilog -> {Blue,
    Arrow[{#[[1]], #[[1]] + Normalize[#[[2]]]/5}] & /@ list,
    Black, Line[Partition[Transpose[list][[1]], 3, 1]],
    Red,
    Arrow[{list[[1, 1]], list[[1, 1]] + Normalize[list[[1, 2]]]/5}]}],
 {{δ, 0.4}, 0.1, 0.9}, {s, 0, π/4},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 SaveDefinitions -> True
]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Version Update**

```
list = {};
DynamicModule[{list,φ,p1, p2, bf = False, pf = False, df = 0.4, sf = 0},
 Manipulate[
  p1 = {x[φ, δ], y[φ, δ]};
  If[df != δ, list = {}; bf = False; pf = False]; df = δ;
  If[sf != φ, p2 = Through[{Cos, Sin}[φ + π/2]]/4]; sf = φ;
  If[! pf, 
   Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[p1 + p2, (p2 = Normalize[# - p1]/4) &]],
    Prolog -> {Blue,
      If[list =!= {} && bf, {Opacity[0.2],
        Arrowheads[Small], 
        Arrow[{#[[1]], #[[1]] + Normalize[#[[2]]]/4}] & /@ list,
        Black, Line[Partition[Transpose[list][[1]], 3, 1]],
        Red, Opacity[1], Arrowheads[Medium], 
        Arrow[{list[[1, 1]],list[[1, 1]] + Normalize[list[[1, 2]]]/4}]}],
      Black, 
      ParametricPlot[{x[θ,δ], y[θ,δ]}, {θ, 0, 4 π}][[1]],
      Orange, PointSize[Large], Point[p1], Thick, 
      Dynamic@Arrow[{p1, p1 + p2}]
      }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1, 1}}, 
    ImageSize -> 300],
   lines = Partition[Transpose[list][[1]], 3, 1];
   Animate[Graphics[{Opacity[0.2], Line@lines[[;;t]]},
     Epilog -> {
       Black, 
       ParametricPlot[{x[θ,δ], y[θ,δ]}, {θ, 0, 4 π}][[1]],
       Orange, PointSize[Large], Point[p1], Thick, 
       Dynamic@Arrow[{p1, p1 + p2}]
       }, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1, 1}}, 
     ImageSize -> 300], {t, 1, Length[lines], 1}, Paneled -> False, 
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
   ],
  Pane[Row[{
     Pane[Column[{
        Row[{Button[" Run ", bf = True; pf = False; 
           list = NestList[next[#][δ] &, {{x[φ,δ], y[φ,δ]}, p2}, 10]],
          Dynamic@Button[If[! pf, " Play ", " Back "], pf = ! pf,
            Enabled -> bf, 
            Background -> If[! pf, Automatic, Orange]]}],
        Row[Button["+" <> ToString@#,
            list = Join[list, NestList[next[#][δ] &,
               If[list === {}, 
                If[bf, {{x[φ,δ], y[φ,δ]}, p2}], 
                Last[list]], #]], Enabled -> Dynamic@bf] & /@ {5, 10, 20}]}
       ], ImageMargins -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0}}],
     Pane[Column[{
        Control@{{δ, 0.4}, 0.1, 0.9},
        Control[{{φ,π/4}, 0, 2 π}]}]]}]],
  ContinuousAction -> True,
  SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

**Example**

> [image: Blockquote]

or

> [image]

Comment: +1, There was an error in the parametrization formula I had provided, now they are corrected, you may want to edit your provided answer accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could add `Red,
    Arrow[{list[[1,1]], list[[1,1]] + Normalize[list[[1,2]]]/5}]` after `Blue,Arrow...` so that the initial position can always be found (shown in red then).